# ¿Cómo uso Grep para filtrar según varias condiciones?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio el cual estoy un poco atascado. Se trata de realizar una expresión regular para utilizarlo con grep en linux, que cumpla con lo siguiente:

> • El campo con el identificador (user) sea mayor o igual a 10 y menor
> que 99.
>
> • Sea relativo exclusivamente a mujeres (sexo femenino).
>
> • Edad comprendida entre los rangos de edad de 10 a 19 años y de 30 a
> 39, ambos inclusive.
>
> • La lengua nativa sea el finlandés y además sepan también hablar el
> español y el francés.

La estructura de los datos es la siguiente:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
```

He intentado construir dicha expresión de la siguiente manera:

```
^[0-9]*(F?)^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*
```

Pero no me trae los datos, y no entiendo muy bien aun sobre expresiones regulares. **¿Qué esta fallando, o que le falta?**

Comment: uy esto en Awk sería mucho más rápido

Comment: además, la priemra condición no la cumple ninguna línea

Comment: Debe ser regex? a simple vista un `if` normal podría funcionar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si no cambia el orden de los idiomas hablados, esto podría funcionar, puede eliminar las mayúsculas si no la necesita, estoy usando el compilador de javascript, pero no creo que haya alguna diferencia

```
^[0-9]{2},F,[13][0-9],finnish,[a-zA-Z\s]*english[a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z]*$
```

Si los idiomas hablados cambian de orden esta debería funcionar

```
^[0-9]{2},F,[13][0-9],finnish,(([a-zA-Z\s]*english[a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z]*)|([a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z\s]*english[a-zA-Z]*))$
```

La primera parte (después de ^) `[0-9]{2}` es para especificar un numero de dos cifras, tenga en cuenta de `09` lo toma como valido, no quiere eso cambie  a `[1-9][0-9]`

Después viene un texto que no cambia `,F,` (entendí que solo mujeres)

La otra parte es `[13][0-9]` este es un numero que empiece con 0 o 3 y termine con uno del 0 al 9

Sigue la parte estatica que es `,finnish,`

Después es la parte `[a-zA-Z\s]*english[a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z]*` que solo  ignora cualquer letra o espacio hasta encontrar la palabra english, y después lo mismo hasta encontrar spanish, la expresión regular para los idiomas cambiados solo es un `|` (or) que cambia los orden, o es uno o el otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora todo mas claro

Comment: hola, acabo de hacer la prueba pero la parte ```[a-zA-Z\s]*english[a-zA-Z\s]*spanish [a-zA-Z]*``` parece ser la que descarta todo.