# regex - ignorar caracteres hasta una palabra concreta

Tags: regex, bash

A partir de la duda comentada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494649/la-expresi%C3%B3n-regular-no-funciona-como-espero), he estado probando el código pero no entiendo el regex que se propone, ni he podido comprobar que funcione correctamente.

CSV inicial:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
```

Respuesta que plantean para cumplir:
• El campo con el identificador (user) sea mayor o igual a 10 y menor que 99.

• Sea relativo exclusivamente a mujeres (sexo femenino).

• Edad comprendida entre los rangos de edad de 10 a 19 años y de 30 a 39, ambos inclusive.

• La lengua nativa sea el finlandés y además sepan también hablar el español y el francés.

```
grep -E '^[0-9]{2},F,[13][0-9],finnish,(([a-zA-Z\s]*french[a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z]*)|([a-zA-Z\s]*spanish[a-zA-Z\s]*french[a-zA-Z]*))$' data.csv
```

Es `[a-zA-Z\s]*` el regex que hace que se ignore el texto hasta llegar a la palabra *'french'* en este caso?

Al ejecutar desde el terminal el código, no obtengo resultados. No obstante, hay una respuesta al menos que sí que debe cumplir:
`9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [La expresión regular no funciona como espero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494649/la-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-no-funciona-como-espero)

Comment: Bueno, ya te dijeron antes que `grep` no es ka herramienta correcta. Ahora que hiciste la pregunta muchísimo mas complicada, es aun menos la herramienta correcta. Porque insistes usar `grep`?

Comment: Además, en tu ejemplo no hay ninguna linea que cumple los requisitos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como con tu pregunta anterior, el `grep` realmente no es la herramienta correcta. Se puede hacer con `grep`, pero esto ya es algo que no es normal intentar hacer con una expresión regular. Pero bueno, usando GNU `grep` con PCREs, tienes:

```
grep -P '^\d{2},F,(1[0-9]|3[1-9]),finnish.*spanish' file | grep french
```

O, si tienes que hacerlo con un proceso solo:

```
grep -P '^\d{2},F,(1[0-9]|3[1-9]),finnish.*((spanish.*french)|(french.*spanish))' file
```

O, si no tienes restricciones raras, en `awk`:

```
awk -F, '/^[0-9]{2},F,(1[0-9]|3[1-9]),finnish/ && /spanish/ && /french/' file
```

O, aun mejor, describiendo cada campo:

```
awk -F, '$1>9 && $1<99 && $2=="F" && 
    (($3>=10 && $3<=19) || ($3>=30 && $3<=39)) && 
    $4=="finnish" && $5 ~ /spanish/ && $5 ~ /french/' file
```

Comment: Tu primera expresión regular no cubre el hecho de que un valor que inicie con `00` se te escape. Por ejemplo: *00,F,23,swedish,finnish english*. Porque le pides que tenga dos digitos, que no es lo mismo que "sea mayor o igual que 10". Igual te voto arriba.

Comment: @Cuauhtli tienes razón, gracias. Pero dado que aquí sabemos que los números empiezan de `0`, no creo que será un problema. Y en todo caso, la solución correcta aquí es el `awk` que si que funcionaría bien mismo con `00`. Podría hacer `grep -P '^[1-9]{2}` por ejemplo pero as un poco tonto hacerlo con grep todo eso...

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que esta expresión regular es un tanto más completa:

```
^([1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]),F,(1[0-9]|3[0-9]),finnish,(?=.*spanish)(?=.*french).+
```

Que explicada sería algo así:

- `^([1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]),`, el primer campo es entre 10 y 98 inclusivos (evito el 00 y el 99 ya que pediste que fueran explícitamente menor a 99)
- `F,`, femenino
- `(1[0-9]|3[0-9]),`, un número entre 10 y 19 inclusivos, o 30 y 39 inclusivo
- `finnish,`, finlandés
- `(?=.*spanish)(?=.*french)`, que tenga tanto la cadena *spanish* como *french* sin importar el orden
- `.+`, y ya que después de pasar esta condicional, que matchee todo

[Ejemplo usando regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/fNQKsO/1)